# Image is rotated and stretched automatically using Open CV iOS. How to fix?

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv

I am using OpenCV 3. I have installed the framework in my Xcode project using POD. To convert the image (Captured by camera) into black and white, I am using *Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding*. Below is the code I have used

```
@implementation MyClass

+(UIImage *)toBlackAndWhite:(UIImage *)s {    
        cv::Mat input;
cv::Mat output;
input = [MyClass cvMatFromUIImage:s];
cv::cvtColor(input, input, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
output = cv::Mat(input.cols, input.rows, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cv::adaptiveThreshold(input, output, 255,CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,CV_THRESH_BINARY, 75, 25);
return [MyClass imageWithCVMat:output];    
}
//Ref:Open CV documentation
+ (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage);
    CGFloat cols = image.size.width;
    CGFloat rows = image.size.height;

    cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels (color channels + alpha)

    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,                 // Pointer to  data
                                                    cols,                       // Width of bitmap
                                                    rows,                       // Height of bitmap
                                                    8,                          // Bits per component
                                                    cvMat.step[0],              // Bytes per row
                                                    colorSpace,                 // Colorspace
                                                    kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                                    kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); // Bitmap info flags

    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image.CGImage);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);

    return cvMat;
}

//Ref:Open CV documentation
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize() * cvMat.total()];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1) {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    } else {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,                                     // Width
                                        cvMat.rows,                                     // Height
                                        8,                                              // Bits per component
                                        8 * cvMat.elemSize(),                           // Bits per pixel
                                        cvMat.step[0],                                  // Bytes per row
                                        colorSpace,                                     // Colorspace
                                        kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,  // Bitmap info flags
                                        provider,                                       // CGDataProviderRef
                                        NULL,                                           // Decode
                                        false,                                          // Should interpolate
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault);                     // Intent

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return image;
}


@end
```

Problem: The image I'm getting, is rotated 90°, anti-clock wise and stretched. Please suggest something how can I fix it. Please see

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GSxU.jpg)

[Processed Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NriwE.jpg)

Comment: You switched cols and rows. Mat constructor is Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type). 
Moreover you use BGR2GRAY which converts 3 channels to 1, but cvMatFromUIImage returns 4 channel Mat.

Comment: @ZuOverture how to fix this?

Comment: in my case orientation is proper but image is getting stretched

Comment: You should be using the OpenCV functions for converting between a Mat & UIImage, this answer covers that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54485811/opencv-ios-type/54486263#54486263

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the `UIImageOrientation` of `UIImage`.

**Background:**
When you hold iPhone at landscape mode(Home button at right side), took a photo, that photo has 'Up' orientation(Yes, this is default). So when you took a photo at portrait mode, the orientation is 'Right'. For a 'Right' orientation photo(portrait), they are saved still at landscape mode actually. The photo looks well when you view it because the 'UIImage' automatically rotated it from landscape mode to portrait. (Rotated it to right, 90 degree, width -> height, height -> width)

**How the stretch problem occurs？**
For photos which have 'Right' and 'Left' orientation, the rotated `UIImage` data will be converted to OpenCV `Mat` object, that makes the 'width' and 'height' **swapped**.
**Solution**: We need to give the original 'width' and 'height' to `Mat`, which is at landscape mode. The `CGImage` property of an `UIImage` has the  image data with original 'width' and 'height', we can use it.

**How the ‘rotated 90°’ problem occurs？**
The OpenCV `Mat` object doesn't keep the orientation info, so the orientation is lost after we converted `UIImage` to `Mat`, and converted it back.
**Solution:** Keep the orientation and apply it to result `UIImage` object.

**Code related to the question:**

```
+(UIImage *)toBlackAndWhite:(UIImage *)s {
     //Create an image with original width and height  
     UIImage *imageUp = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[s CGImage]];
     //......
     input = [MyClass cvMatFromUIImage:imageUp];

     //......

     UIImage *handledImage = [MyClass imageWithCVMat:output];  
     //Set orientation to the result image
     UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[handledImage CGImage] scale:[s scale] orientation: s.imageOrientation];
     return finalImage;
}
```

Comment: We need to give the original 'width' and 'height' to Mat, which is at landscape mode. The CGImage property of an UIImage has the image data with original 'width' and 'height', we can use it.


how to get original size?

Comment: your solution is helpful but I am not getting how to get original width and height

Comment: in my case orientation is proper but image is getting stretched

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora, an image created from CGImage has the original size. In the above example, `imageUp.size` is the original size.

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora, yes. You give the OpenCV the right size image, then OpenCV will handle it appropriately. At last, you set the `imageOrientation` to the result image, it could be displayed correctly on the iPhone.