# Opencv iOS type

Tags: ios, opencv

Im trying to create methods to convert UIImage to Mat and vice versa, but an "Expected a type" error keeps popping up for (cv::Mat) when I try to build. When I clean my project there are no errors.

I'v tried looking around to find different data types, but nothing seems to work. I assume the error is somewhere in importing the OpenCV module, but I am not sure.

```
#ifdef _cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface OpenCVWrapper : NSObject

- (id)init;
- (UIImage *)edgeDetection:(UIImage *)source;
- (cv::Mat)matFrom:(UIImage *)image;                  //error
- (UIImage *)imageFrom:(cv::Mat)cvMat;                //error

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV provides functions for doing these conversions for you:

```
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>

- (cv::Mat)matWithImage:(UIImage *)image {
    MAT dst;
    UIImageToMat(image, dst);
    return dst;
}

- (UIImage *)imageWithCVMat:(cv::Mat)source {
    return MatToUIImage(source);
}
```