# Why my picture resolution are very bad with UIImage in swift

Tags: ios, swift4, opencv3.1

I use the following function to make picture `photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: AVCapturePhotoSettings(), delegate: self)`.

When I save the picture his weight is only about 200Ko however the size with the AVCaptureSession.presset is `.hight` so it's make 1920x1080.

there is m'y prepare function to change view where all "image" var are UIImage :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showPhoto_Segue"{
        let previewVC = segue.destination as! PreviewViewController
        previewVC.image = self.image

    }
}
```

in my photoOutput function I have :

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

    if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation(){
        image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        Arrayimages.append(image!)
        Arraytimes.append(Float64(CMTimeGetSeconds(currentCamera!.exposureDuration)))
    }
    if pictureNumber < 11 {
        pictureNumber += 1
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + newDurationSeconds + 0.3, execute: {
            self.photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: AVCapturePhotoSettings(), delegate: self)
        })
    }
    else{
        image = OpenCVWrapper.hdrImaging(Arrayimages, Arraytimes)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPhoto_Segue", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

In my OpenCVWrapper.mm I have :

```
+(UIImage *) hdrImaging:(NSArray *)images :(NSArray *)times{
    std::vector<cv::Mat> imagesVector;
    std::vector<float> timesVector;
    for (int i = 0; i < images.count; i++) {
        UIImage * imageToUse = images[i];

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToUse, nil, nil, nil);
    }

    //some traitment
    return response;
}
```

when I use UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function my pictures are already compressed but I don't know why and the weight of the file is to small to get good quality !

what can I do to get full resolution of my piture in 1920x1080 ?

maybe with AVCapturePhotoSettings ??

thanks!

Comment: I don't see where you are converting your `UIImage` into a `cv::Mat`, as that is likely where the issue is. You can look at this to get the OpenCV functions for performing these conversions in case that fixes your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54485811/opencv-ios-type/54486263#54486263

Comment: the probleme is directly in the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum who store my picture with bad resolution